# DRI_PRIME doesnt work

Tags: radeon, switchable-graphics

I have a HP G6-2251ST(7420g+7670m). Im following the procedure below to make my 7670m work but performance seems to stay same. Here is what ive done;

```
xrandr --listproviders 
Providers: number : 3
Provider 0: id: 0x7c cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 3 associated providers: 2 name:radeon
Provider 1: id: 0x45 cap: 0x6, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 6 outputs: 0 associated providers: 2 name:radeon
Provider 2: id: 0x45 cap: 0x6, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 6 outputs: 0 associated providers: 2 name:radeon



xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink 1 0


DRI_PRIME=1 steam steam://rungameid/240
```

Comment: Actually what is the exact issue that prevents your 7670M from working? Please state that. It might be necessary.

Comment: the commands above are to switch between my two graphics cards.the problem is, all the commands are executed w/o any error and by that rendering is done on the 7670m and displaying results is done on 7420g(integrated gpu). But it seems the performance stays exactly same as if my system running on integrated gpu.

Answer (score 3):

I seem to have a similar setup, and it is working for me. Can you perhaps try this one?

```
xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink 0x45 0x7c
```

In order to see whether it actually works it can be interesting to use something else than steam, like glxgears.

```
glxgears
DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears
```

The latter should show a higher fps in the console than the first. For me it is 60 FPS compared to 3995 (???) FPS.

On a side note, DRI_PRIME is great, but does not really work well with the fancy compositors like the one used by Ubuntu Unity. I installed xfce, which I log in to for gaming only, as that works way better. But first try to get steam working on your dedicated GPU :)

Comment: it looks like working in glxgears. igp 60fps dgp 1640fps approximately. thats also weird. igp is worse than dgp thats clear but not that bad.

Comment: Dont really seen how that is weird :). With DRI_PRIME you get higher fps, so sounds good to me. Another thing I do: I start steam with 'DRI_PRIME=1 steam'. Nothing more. You can then go to steam system information and it should show decent graphics info. Any game you launch from steam will then be running with DRI_PRIME.

Comment: Its odd because fps with my discrete gpu shouldnt make that much of a difference even if we compare it to a intagrated chip. When i start steam with "DRI_PRIME=1 steam", it starts fine but after launching a game ,cs source in my trial, it freezes at startup but sound comes in backgound. then i open up console in game and type "exit" without seeing anything finally game closes where i find myself at ubuntu spash screen.

Comment: Aha, sounds like the compositor problem! I bet you are using Unity. I advice to try out xfce (as it works for me) or run the game in a window. Note that installing xfce in Ubuntu does make some weird things happen to things like themes and such.

Comment: yes,i installed xfce and tried css both with and w/o DRI_PRIME=1 steam i got 79.05fps with it and 80.95fps w/o it.thanks for the solution. i think the cpu limits my discrete card thats why i cant get its full potential.thats my final thought on this.

Answer (score 0):

`vblank_mode=0` should unlock your FPS in game.